# Matlab: Call function that has no outputs from an anonymous function

Tags: matlab, lambda

I'd like to call a certain function from within an anonymous function, as in

```
@(){fooBar(baz)}
```

Trouble is, `fooBar` has no outputs, which makes the anonymous function complain. Is there a way around this besides making the `fooBar` function return a dummy output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in your anonymous function definition. By enclosing your function `foobar(baz)` between the characters `{...}`, you are programming a function which has to :

- evaluate the expression `foobar(baz)`
- Place the result of this expression into a `cell`
- return the cell

Obviously in step (2) Matlab cannot place the result of the expression (1) in a cell because there is no output from (1).

So simply define your function without the curly braces:

```
myFunction = @() fooBar(baz)
```

and everything should work ok.

---

To demonstrate with an example, let's define the function `fooBar` by doing something which does not produce an output (change an axe limits for example):

```
fooBar = @(axlim) set(gca,'XLim',axlim)
```

I can now call `fooBar([0 20])` and the current axes will directly have its axes limits set to `[0 20]`

If there is an axis span which I use often ([-5 5] for example), I could be tempted to define a new function which will always call `fooBar` with the same (often used) parameters:

```
fooBarPrefered = @() fooBar([-5 5])
```

Now every time I call `fooBarPrefered()`, my axes X limits are directly set to [-5 5].

---

To further prove the point, since calling `fooBar([-5 5])` does not produce an output, Matlab will indeed complain if I define my function with curly braces:

```
fooBarPrefered = @() {fooBar([-5 5])} ;
>> fooBarPrefered()
One or more output arguments not assigned during call to "set".
Error in @(axlim)set(gca,'XLim',axlim)

Error in @(){fooBar([-5,5])}
```

But note that this is the same error than if you were trying to assign the output of `fooBar` to a variable directly in the workspace:

```
a = fooBar([0 20])
One or more output arguments not assigned during call to "set".
Error in @(axlim)set(gca,'XLim',axlim)
```

---

Bottom line: If a function does not have an output, do not try to redirect this output to a variable or an expression.

Comment: Oh! I thought those braces were part of the anonymous function syntax. It does indeed work without them. Thanks!